# Call a user defined function defined in schemaA from a view defined in SchemaB SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having a problem to call a function from my view. They are both in different schemas, so I have something like this:

```
View [SchemaA].[ViewName]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
        SELECT DISTINCT
             [SchemaB].[functionName](value) as 'variable'
        FROM
            //Several selects with joins
```

The problem is that I am getting this error: *"Cannot schema bind view 'SchemaA.view'. 'SchemaB.functionName' is not schema bound."*

I have also tried to include the database name in the call to the function like this:

```
[database].[SchemaB].[functionName]
```

But it still didn't work. However it returned a different error: *"Cannot schema bind view 'SchemaA.view' because name 'SchemaB.functionName' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself."*

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try `[database.SchemaB].[functionName]`

Comment: That returns this error: *"Cannot find either column "database.SchemaB" or the user-defined function or aggregate "database.SchemaB.functionName", or the name is ambiguous."*

Comment: The error message is telling you that there's an issue *with the function*, not in *how you're trying to call it*.

Comment: Are you missing the schema's owner out: `[SchemaA].[dbo].[functionName]`?

Comment: It had to do with the function itself, it needed to include the schemabinding flag as well. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be schema bound (`WITH SCHEMABINDING`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION SchemaBinded(@INPUT INT)
RETURNS INT WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
RETURN @INPUT * 2 + 50
END
GO
```